# AjaxSubmit is not a function on DOM reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, ajaxform

I have this code below.

```
$('body').on('submit', '.some-form', function (event) {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, statusText, xhr, form) {
            var url = 'some/url';

            // Reload the form markup/DOM using the response
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'get',
                url: url
            }).done(function (html) {
                // get markup from url and replace the form markup ...    
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    return false; 
});
```

Essentially what I am doing here is

1. submit and process the form
2. get the results
3. if success, get new form markup from a page then replace the current form markup.
   if failure, show error

Now, because I delegated the submit event to the body, there shouldn't be a problem with
handling the submit on the newly loaded form markup.

The function handler works fine until I see this error

```
TypeError: $(...).ajaxSubmit is not a function

error: function () {
```

Any idea why this happened? It implies that ajaxSubmit does not exist but I did not reload
the page.

EDIT: Yes, I am using the [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery Form Plugin?

Comment: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Indeed, my thoughts were where the heck is the ajaxSubmit function coming from.

Comment: Why you need ajaxsubmit? Jquery Ajax can do the above.

Comment: @STEEL Because I need to upload files via Ajax.

Comment: So it works one time but when you submit again you get the error?

Comment: When I click on the new markup, loaded via JS, I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

My money is on the following:

In your request for HTML:

`// get markup from url and replace the form markup ...`

you're loading a full page which contains a jQuery library. When you do that, the new jQuery script in the HTML response will be downloaded parsed and executed and it will overwrite the current jQuery prototype meaning that jQuery.ajaxSubmit is no longer accessible.

Pretty clever, eh?

The best way to solve this is to simply not request the full page that contains the jQuery script, instead, request a URL that only contains the DOM structure that you want, rather than the full page including headers, footers, scripts, etc.

Comment: Seems to me that I am already doing it. The page that I cam calling does not include extraneous data such as the headers, footers or the layout.

Comment: Alrighty, but I can guarantee you that if you look in your network tab, then you'll see a new jQuery script being downloaded after you execute your request the first time. Try this, `console.log($)` and `console.log($.fn)` before your `$(this).ajaxSubmit()` - this first time you'll see that `ajaxSubmit` is a method of the `$.fn` object, and the second time you won't, but when you `console.log($)` it should appear to be the same. This means that your `$.fn` got overridden somewhere after the first request but before the second request meaning $.ajaxSubmit will no longer be accessible.